# Finding vector from curl of vector

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider the following

\begin{equation}
\nabla\phi=\nabla\times \vec{A}.
\end{equation}

Is it possible to find $\vec{A}$ from the above equation and if so, how does one go about doing so?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Inverse

Comment: I am trying to find the components of $A$, if it's at all possible. Hence, I am not sure if the wiki article helps.

Comment: why doesn't it help? The curl is not invertible in general though since if there was such a solution $A$, you can always add $\nabla f$ (for some scalar function $f$) to your solution and still satisfy the equation

Comment: Does that mean that $A$ is in general, not unique and hence I might as well stop at the above equation?

Comment: Correct, $A$ cannot be unique (not terribly surprising since even simple antiderivatives are not unique, except up to a constant). I'm not sure what your application is, but the closest thing I can think of to "inverting" a curl would be a Helmholtz decomposition as wiki points out.

Comment: I have an equation that involves the components of $A$. As such, I was wondering how to extract out the components of $A$ from the above equation.

Comment: Let $\vec V$ be any vector field satisfying $\nabla \times \vec V = 0$. Such $\vec V$ are somestimes called "gauge fields". Then $$\nabla \vec A = \nabla (\vec A + \vec V)$$ Thus your equation only defines $\vec A$ up to the addition of a gauge field. There are many such fields, far beyond just constant fields, so no, you cannot determine the components of $\vec A$ from that equation alone. You need to have additional conditions that restrict the problem to a unique answer. But you can extract certain properties of the components from that equation. If those are not enough, you are out of luck